# c++ sdl window freeze and issues with sdl

Tags: c++, sdl

SDL just pisses me off, please help. 
I'm trying just to show a window, this is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include "SDL.h"

int main()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 600, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (window == NULL)
        return 1;
    SDL_Event event;
    bool running = true;
    while (running) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    running = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    SDL_Quit();
    std::cout << "Hello :)" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the issue is that it says that the program now responding and I have a "loading" icon for the mouse. Second issue is that I cannot use SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING for some reason, it just gets stuck and nothing outputs when I try to output after init. 
I tried multiple sdl files x86 , x64. 
I have windows 10 64bit OS. 
I really start to lose my sanity here , please help.

EDIT :

the window works perfectly fine with SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING but it takes the computer to load everything for 1 minute and 50 seconds. which is a lot of time.

But when I only init SDL_INIT_VIDEO , it's not responding. 
Any solution ?

Comment: In the first case: can you click the x button to close the window?

Comment: @ubadub when I use SDL_INIT_VIDEO not I cannot. 
When I use SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING I can but it takes 2 minutes to load the screen and show it up.

Comment: anyone ? please help :(

Comment: Why are you defining `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED`? It doesn't look like you even know what it's used for. You might just want to follow a tutorial or something, because you are missing an important thing that pretty much every program does: delay. In any case, this is hardly the fault of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I have downloaded an older version 2.0.5 instead of the new "stable" version and seems like it works. I guess the new version just have bugs that needs to be fixed.